# Finding out what's taking up the CMA (Contiguous Memory Allocation) in Linux

Tags: linux

Something is definitely taking up the `CMA` buffers, but I can't figure out what.

```
# cat /proc/meminfo | grep -i cma
CmaTotal:         262144 kB
CmaFree:            1272 kB
```

The system messages show little nothing:

```
# dmesg | grep -i cma
[    0.000000] cma: Reserved 256 MiB at 0x00000000c0000000
```

I've enabled `debugfs` for `cma`, but I have not yet figured out how to use it:

```
/sys/kernel/debug/cma/cma-reserved# ls
alloc  base_pfn  bitmap  count  free  maxchunk  order_per_bit  used
```

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure how or *if* you can find out *who* uses the CMA areas (i'd very much like to know, myself), but I think that I have figured out how to use the debugfs.

The files in the /sys/kernel/debug/cma/cma-reserved directory that you are ls'ing contain information about CMA areas, expressed in page frame numbers (PFNs) and number of pages.

If you `cat /sys/kernel/debug/cma/cma-reserved/base_pfn`, for instance, you will see the PFN of the physical memory address from which the CMA area begins.

Similarly, the files `count`, `used`, and `maxchunk` contain the number of pages that are reserved for the CMA area, the number of those pages that is currently in use, and the max number of pages that is currently available for allocation. Multiply their contents with the PAGE_SIZE of your system in order to get the amount in Bytes.

`alloc` and `free` aren't readable but you can use them to manually reserve up to maxchunk number of pages and to free any of the so previously reserved areas, using:

```
echo X > /sys/kernel/debug/cma/cma-reserved/alloc
```

or

```
echo X > /sys/kernel/debug/cma/cma-reserved/free
```

respectively.

`bitmap` is another readable file that contains, well... a bitmap of used or unused pages.

Check also: https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/mm/cma_debugfs.html